# Run program while computer is cool

Tags: scheduling, job-control

I'm trying to compile a program on a computer with inadequate cooling.

The program, specifically, is the `linux-ck` kernel with `-mtune=native march=native` processor-specific optimizations, so simply running it on a different computer defeats the purpose.

We are currently trying to solve the cooling issues. **NOTE:** I don't have physical access to the computer, so please do not try to help me troubleshoot it.

I, instead, need a way to pause the program (shell job control '`^Z`-style') when the CPU gets above a certain temperature, as measured by `sensors`, and resume it once the temperature is measured to be back to safe levels.

**NOTE:** This computer has reached 91°C before.

The computer is running Arch Linux and is fully updated.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to assign a PID of main job to variable and write a script which:

- checks say every ~10 seconds the temperature. Something like

  ```
  temp=($(sensors | awk -F'[+.]' '{print $2}'))
  ```

  creates a table `temp` with two temperatures (acpitz and coretemp) on my box, you may need to adjust it for you output of `sensors`.
- if temp > $TEMPMAX sends `kill -TSTP PID` to the job (CTRL-Z, aka suspend)

  ```
  (( $temp[1] > 80 || $temp[2] > 80 )) && kill -TSTP $JOBPID
  ```
- if temp < $TEMPRUN sends `kill -CONT PID` to the job (the same as bg command)

  ```
  (( $temp[1] < 40 && $temp[2] < 40 )) && kill -CONT $JOBPID
  ```

Since the script will be executed very often you may want to get a temp from the source instead of the `sensors` command to gain on speed a little bit. On may machine this works:

```
temp=($(cut -c 1-2 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input) $(cut -c 1-2 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/device/temp2_input))
```

but again, you may need to tune it for your needs.

Comment: Aha! The trick as the `kill -TSTP` and `kill -CONT` signals. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - make sure to mark this as accepted if it solved your issue!

Comment: @slm Yes - I've upvoted it for now. As soon as I get a script cobbled together to accomplish this task, I'll mark it as accepted. (For now, though, it's got a lot off work to do. The command to extract the temperature from the sensors is totally nonfunctional, for example. And I don't know awk or sed or anything like that, so it'll likely be a while.)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - np, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude It is very likely that your `sensors` gives something different than mine, simple because the output depends on specific hardware (such as number of CPU cores, etc.) and kernel modules. Please post your output so we will see how one can parse it. But once again, I rather recommend to take temp from the file `/sys/class/...` (of course exact location can also be different that in my example)